# Оператор ! после значения переменной в C#

Tags: c#

Что за оператор `!` в этом участке кода:

```
private string SmthMethod()
{
    return "1234"!; //Почему нет ошибки компиляции? Что это за знак вопроса?
}
```

Comment: `"1234"` вы написали? Если да, пример не очень. А так, это [Оператор, допускающий NULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). То есть, это когда вы уверены, что в данном участке кода, возвращать `null` допустимо, но студия вам выделила это и говорит "тут возвращается null, плохо!", вот вы при помощи `!` глушите это, написав `return null!;`. Как написано по ссылке выше (`Оператор, допускающий NULL, ни на что не влияет во время выполнения. Он влияет только на статический анализ`), это не влияет каким образом на работу самого кода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ неплохой ответ в виде комментария, можно было ответом.

Comment: @aepot Предоставлю это другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если простыми словами, то этот знак обозначает, что переменная или значение может быть null.

Такое зачастую используют при написании оболочки к различным API, когда сервер может возвращать дополнительные значения. По факту, это лишь для программистов и компилятора